# React state updating multiple times on single setState call

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I have a component that updates the state when a socket message is received. It looks like this:

SocketComponent.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent.js';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:8080");

const testHandler = (data, setState) => {
  console.log(data);
  setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, testDataBoolean: false }));
}

const SocketComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    testDataBoolean: true,
    testDataCount: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (data) => {testHandler(data, setState)};
    socket.on("testEvent", handler);

    return () => {
      socket.off("testEvent", handler);
    };
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      <ExampleComponent visible={state.testDataBoolean} />
      <button onClick={() => socket.emit('testEvent', 'testData')}>Emit Event</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SocketComponent;
```

ExampleComponent.js

```js
import React from 'react';

const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
  if (!props.visible) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>Hello!</div>
  )
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

All the socket code works fine. I emit the "testEvent" after clicking the button and then it goes to the `testHandler` function and calls `setState`. The problem comes in when I'm trying to hide the ExampleComponent. If I put print out what `props.visible` is in ExampleComponent, it prints out the following after clicking the button once:

```
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: true}
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: true}
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: true}
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: true}
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: false}
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: true}
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: false}
ExampleComponent.js:4 {visible: true}
```

This makes the component still visible since the last value is true. Why is React re-rendering it so much after calling setState once within the socket.on callback? Why is the state value being modified so many times as shown in the above logs? How can I make sure it only updates the state value once and to the correct value?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the environment with the code you provided, but there is no socket handler responding on my end

Comment: useEffect triggers once at render and once with the parameters you give him. I'm not familiar with sockets but could this open two sockets ? Would this work putting socket on outside the useEffect ? Also, you could render your component with a condition directly in `SocketComponent.js : {state.testDataBoolean && <ExampleComponent/>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it will solve your problem, but you may want to consider creating your socket inside the `useEffect()` to ensure that it's only initiated once and storing the socket value in a `useRef()` to guarantee that the value doesn't change between re-renders. For example:

```js
  const socket = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (data) => { testHandler(data, setState); };

    socket.current = socketIOClient("http://localhost:8080");
    socket.current.on("testEvent", handler);

    return () => { socket.current.off("testEvent", handler); };
  }, []);
```

Your `onClick()` would then be:

```js
  onClick={() => socket.current.emit('testEvent', 'testData')}
```